# Issue in Mysql database collation

Tags: mysql

Hi I am getting a strange character stored in mysql something like this "�", I have stored the field name as "latin1_swedish_ci" and then changed it to "latin1_spanish_ci" but it still remains, please tell me what to do so that I can remove this character from the database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Try to change the field character set to utf8. Also check the connection string to have something like this connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8

Comment: This needs more detail. Where exactly is this character showing up? On a web site, in a database tool?

Comment: Hi this character shows in the phpmyadmin when you click on edit row